# im having problem when running npm install

Tags: npm-install

Im getting this error when I run npm install....any one who knows how to fix this

gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.20.23.46:443
gyp ERR! stack     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1056:14)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/dev/git/ui/node_modules/node/bin/node" "/Users/dev/git/ui/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/dev/git/ui/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v12.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN @solar/components@2.1.4 requires a peer of ng2-select-compat@1.3.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN less-loader@4.0.2 requires a peer of less@^2.3.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng2-pdf-viewer@4.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng2-select@1.2.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@^2.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng2-select@1.2.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN stylus-loader@3.0.1 requires a peer of stylus@>=0.52.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN micro-ui@2.0.3 No description
npm WARN micro-ui@2.0.3 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.12.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.12.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/dev/.npm/_logs/2019-07-16T08_04_06_803Z-debug.log

Comment: You need to install `postinstall`.

Comment: Please edit your question. Indent your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `node-sass` version is too old for `node` version. Either use a compatible
version on node or use a newer version of `node-sass`.
You can update `node-sass` with `npm` update `node-sass` if the parent package allows.